# When is best for the extra recover day?

Tags: running, training

I am training to reduce my 10K run performance, aiming to go under 6m/k.

My program is built of 3 runs a week, 1 is an interval run, 1 is an LSD (Long Slow Distance at 75% HR) and the other is a power run.

As the runs are "every other day", one of them still can get an extra recovery day.

My question:

What will I gain if I take the extra day after the Interval runs?

- What about after the LSD run?

Answer (score 3):

Pay attention to your body, and which of your workouts is 'hurting' you more?  This may change over time as you get stronger at each aspect.

Consider rotating or moving the extra rest day to support the aspect you are weakest in, at the moment, since it is the recovery that makes you stronger as the muscles recover and rebuild.

Comment: If I'd listen to my body, I would stay in bed :-)

Answer (score 1):

The best sign of overtraining is my pulse. I check it before getting out of bed in the morning. And if the puls difference between my usual morning pulse and overtrained one more than 10-15 along for 3-4 days, I will take an extra recover day.

After LSD runs you may parctise 30 min recovery run (60% MaxHR) on next day.